# Searching with a column that has `|` character as its value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

With `a` as a column in table `b`, I'd like to understand why the search fetches a row for `a=0` condition!

```
mysql> select * from (select "0|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
+--------------------+
| a                  |
+--------------------+
| 0|679501|3371371|0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select "079501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from (select "None|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
+-----------------------+
| a                     |
+-----------------------+
| None|679501|3371371|0 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select "null|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
+-----------------------+
| a                     |
+-----------------------+
| null|679501|3371371|0 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from (select "679501|null|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has to do with complex MySQL casting rules.  The good news is that you'll probably never actually have to do something like this in a real world query.

Comment: You can narrow this behavior down by examining simply, for example, `select 0="0|1|2";` versus `select 0="1|2|0";` and `select 0="null|1|2";`. Also try `select 0="foo|1|2";`. It illustrates that MySQL is doing a "string to int" and stops parsing at `|`. If you "string to int" on something other than a string starting with a number, it gives 0, so `0="abc"` is truthy. C's `atoi` would behave similarly in these cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, bot really, I had a similar case with a larger table. Thats why I had to understand the possible cases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results have nothing to do with the fact that the delimiter you are using is `|`. It would be the same with any non-numeric character. Likewise, neither `null` nor `None` are special in this context. That could be any string.

In the expression, `0="0|679501|3371371|0"`, MySQL is doing a "string to int" on the string and comparing with 0. It's behavior is similar to how `atoi` in C works. Parsing stops at the first non-numeric character. If the string doesn't start with a numeric character, then it yields 0.

You can simplify examining the behavior with the following queries:

```
> select 0="0|1|2";
+-----------+
| 0="0|1|2" |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"0|1|2"` converted to an integer is 0. Parsing stops at `|`. Comparing 0=0 gives 1.

```
> select 0="0x1x2";
+-----------+
| 0="0x1x2" |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"0x1x2"` converted to an integer is 0. Parsing stops at `|`. Comparing 0=0 gives 1.

```
> select 0="1|2|0";
+-----------+
| 0="1|2|0" |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"1|2|0"` converted to an integer is 1. Parsing stops at `|`. Comparing 0=1 gives 0.

```
> select 1="1x2x0";
+-----------+
| 1="1x2x0" |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"1x2x0"` converted to an integer is 1. Parsing stops at `|`. Comparing 1=1 gives 1.

```
> select 0="null|1|2";
+--------------+
| 0="null|1|2" |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"null|1|2"` converted to an integer is 0 since the string doesn't start with a numeric and parsing stops immediately. Default value is 0. Comparing 0=0 gives 1.

```
> select 0="foo|1|2";
+-------------+
| 0="foo|1|2" |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

`"foo|1|2"` converted to an integer is 0 since the string doesn't start with a numeric and parsing stops immediately. Default value is 0. Comparing 0=0 gives 1.

Comment: selecting SELECT NULL|1; returns NULL. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @veri_pudcha_coder that's a different query not related to the ones in this question. Here, you have an expression `null | 1`, not a string.  The `|` is a bitwise OR operator. Evidently, if you have a `null` argument for the bitwise OR, MySQL yields `null` for the whole expression. Same thing happens if you query, `select null + 3;`, you get `null`.

Comment: @lurker cool. If thats the case, null is just a representation of "nothing"! Cool! Thank you.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran yep, that's more or less what `null` means. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of how MySQL casts text/varchar to integer.

`select *, cast(b.a as unsigned) from (select "None|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0` gives `0` for the second column.

If you cast the integer to text, then you get 0 rows as expected:
`select * from (select "None|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a='0'`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an implicit type conversion according to operands [coercibilities](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html). Your first query:

```
select * from (select "0|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
```

returns a row since `0|679501|3371371|0` has a numeric character (`0`) in its beginning which is equal to the other side of comparison on conversion but this:

```
select * from (select "9|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=0;
```

returns null. [MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: but `has a numeric character (0)` means,  in `"9|679501|3371371|0"` 9 is also a numberic character right?

Comment: Yes but but 9 is not equal to the other side of comparison.

Comment: If you run this you will know the difference `select * from (select "9|679501|3371371|0" as a) b where a=9;`